# Mute/unmute myself in Discord programatically (and if possible locally)

Tags: discord, mute

Is there a way to programmatically mute or unmute (later also deafen or un-deafen) myself in Discord (similar to manually doing it by pressing the small microphone icon in the bottom left corner)? I know I can configure a hotkey for this (and yes, I could "trigger" the hotkey programmatically) but that's not what I want here.

Preferably the solution just works locally without calling any REST APIs or such, just by interacting with the local Discord Client through some kind of API, but if that's just absolutely not possible, than calling a REST API would be okay, too.

I tried using the Discord Game SDK, but it seems to be rather limited when it comes to something like this.

Answer (score 0):

The "some kind of API" you're asking for may be the Electron devtools (basically your typical web browser tools). On your Discord client you can open it with `CTRL + SHIFT + I`. Note that they've [disabled it by default](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/sc61n3/comment/hu4fw5x/) on stable builds to keep users safe.

> you can turn it back *on* by setting `"DANGEROUS_ENABLE_DEVTOOLS_ONLY_ENABLE_IF_YOU_KNOW_WHAT_YOURE_DOING": true` in `%appdata%/discord/settings.json`.

You can try interacting with the client through JavaScript on the console.
Whether it's useful to you depends on your requirements though.

Comment: Mmh, that seems veeeery hacky, too. Is there no way using some APIs officially provided by Discord?

Comment: After all somehow it has to work, cause for example the Discord plugin for the Elgato Stream Deck does excatly this. Sadly the code for that isn't open source.

Comment: I've looked into Stream Deck, and see that they do have an authorization step. Among the given permissions is to "interface with local Discord client". Following that trail led me to https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rpc, which I think is [what you're looking for](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rpc#setvoicesettings).

Comment: Yeah, I found that, too, and also thought that it would be what I need. Sadly the site states that RPC is in a private beta and that they're not accepting any new developers into the program at this time. So, it seems, no luck here... T_T

Comment: Discord usually allows developers to use most anything they want while in development (under a certain number of users/servers/etc), so I had interpreted that disclaimer to be only for "approved" use cases. If not, then yeah that's a shame.

Comment: I thought so, too, and today tried getting it to work somehow, but I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or if it no longer works, because I just won't get any responses from my websocket connection. Have you done any tests regarding this?

Comment: No, I haven't touched it myself, but not getting *any* responses seems abnormal indeed. Though perhaps it is to be expected of a "private beta". Also, I noticed on the *Connecting* section that they want you to define an "RPC Origin" and such which I couldn't find on the app panel either (unless I'm blind). It does look more and more like this isn't ready for even a development use case...

Comment: I think you might also want to ask this question on the official [Discord Developers](https://discord.gg/discord-developers) server instead, just in case.

Comment: Yes, I also couldn't find "RPC origin". Will try asking the question on the Discord Developer server, too. Thanks!